# Dividing strings into multiple columns

Tags: r

I extracted data from pdf tables, but it returns a vector with strings. I would like to to become a matrix.

For example,

```
[1] "XX/R011680/2   Fun          9-10   XX/R008108/2     No fun     *N/A"
[2] "XX/X002103/2   Fun         8-8.9   XX/S00257X/2     No fun     *N/A"
[3] "XX/X011443/2   Fun         8-8.9"
[4] "XX/X008728/2   No fun      7-7.9"
```

it is possible to cut it by the spaces somehow. Such that it becomes a matrix like this.

```
     [,1]            [,2]          [,3]       [,4]              [,5]        [,6]
[1] "XX/X011680/2"   "Fun"         "9-10"   "XX/X008108/2"     "No fun"    "*N/A"
[2] "XX/X002103/2"   "Fun"         "8-8.9"  "XX/X00257X/2"     "No fun"    "*N/A"
[3] "XX/X011443/2"   "Fun"         "8-8.9"     NA               NA          NA
[4] "XX/X008728/2"   "No fun"      "7-7.9"     NA               NA          NA
```

or like this if it is easier? 
The position of the rows does not matter as I can sort it out later.

```
   [,1]              [,2]          [,3] 
[1] "XX/X011680/2"   "Fun"        "9-10" 
[2] "XX/X008108/2"   "No fun"     "*N/A"
[3] "XX/X002103/2"   "Fun"        "8-8.9"   
[4] "XX/X00257X/2"   "No fun"     "*N/A"
[5] "XX/X011443/2"   "Fun"        "8-8.9"     
[6] "XX/X008728/2"   "No fun"     "7-7.9"
```

Comment: ? fwf: fixed-width-format https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.1/topics/read.fwf

Comment: ah, I didn't know about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input `L` given reproducibly in the Note below remove the double quotes, translate 2 or more spaces to comma and then read with read.table:

```
L2 <- gsub('"', '', gsub('  +', ',', L))
read.table(text = L2, as.is = TRUE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE)
```

### Note

```
L <- 
c("\"XX/R011680/2   Fun          9-10   XX/R008108/2     No fun     *N/A\"", 
"\"XX/X002103/2   Fun         8-8.9   XX/S00257X/2     No fun     *N/A\"", 
"\"XX/X011443/2   Fun         8-8.9\"", 
"\"XX/X008728/2   No fun      7-7.9\""
)
```